# Dropbox Core API Java - cannot get folder size in metadata

Tags: java, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am using the Dropbox core API in Java to create an app. When I try to get the metadata for a folder, I only get the field's name, iconName and mightHaveThumbnail, contrary to Python, which lists all the details. Am I missing something or does the Java API expose limited information?

I'm just trying to print the metadata via this code:

```
DbxEntry listing = client.getMetadata("/testFolder");<br>
System.out.println(listing.toStringMultiline());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the rest of the metadata, you'll want to cast to a `DbxEntry.Folder`:

```
DbxEntry entry = client.getMetadata("/testFolder");
if (entry instanceof DbxEntry.Folder) {
    DbxEntry.Folder folder = (DbxEntry.Folder)entry;

    System.out.println(folder.toStringMultiline());
}
```

But as Olivier pointed out, folders themselves do not have sizes in Dropbox. If you're interested in how big the files within that folder are, you'll have to sum the sizes yourself.

Comment: Yes. I guess that this is the only way

Answer (score 0):

In the world of Dropbox with Java, a folder [does not have any size](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v1.7.x/com/dropbox/core/DbxEntry.Folder.html).